# how to use where clause in insert statement in php 5.1.6

Tags: php, html, mysql

How to use where clause in insert statement in php 5.1.6?

I have a global variable `$module` and i want to use `where` clause to distinguish my search result. `where module= $module`

I keep on getting error saying undefined variable `$module`

Comment: Can you write the query?

Comment: Are you inserting from a `SELECT` result set? Please show us your code.

Comment: $sql = 'SELECT `id`, `AssignmentName`, `file`, `deadline`,`name`,`module` FROM `Assignment_scripts` where module=`$module`';
    $result = $dbLink->query($sql);

Comment: add `global $module` at the starting.

Comment: I sincerely hope you're escaping your stuff properly!

Comment: @DeepeshThapa - where have you defined that variable and how you are using.. Edit your question using edit link

Comment: Apparently you don't have global variable $module. If you did, you wouldn't be getting the error you're getting.

Comment: I got help from post below.. I just have to replace the single quotation mark to double quotation mark in order to use where condition..

Comment: Seriously, please please upgrade your PHP version. 5.1 has been unsupported for *years*. It has known security flaws that have not and will not be patched. And server software old enough to be compatible with it is also likely to be badly out of date and insecure. You are running major risk of being hacked of you put this kind of server on the public internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>Without knowing anything about your code, I'd guess your problem is that you don't escape your $module variable. try surrounding it with {}.</s>

Example:

$query  = "SELECT * FROM FOOBAR WHERE id = {$module}";

Edit:

OP posted code on comments.

{} only works if you use quotation marks around your variable.

Change you code to :

```
$sql = "SELECT id, AssignmentName, file, deadline,name,module FROM Assignment_scripts where module={$module}";
```

Edit2:

Are you actually defining $module somewhere?

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '}' at line 1

Comment: Could you please post your code so we could help you?

Comment: $sql = 'SELECT `id`, `AssignmentName`, `file`, `deadline`,`name`,`module` FROM `Assignment_scripts` where module=`{$module}`';
    $result = $dbLink->query($sql);

Comment: edited my answer to better resolve the problem

Comment: $module is a global variable

Comment: there is a difference between single quotes (`'`) and double quotes (`"`), from the [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php): `Note: Unlike the double-quoted and heredoc syntaxes, variables and escape sequences for special characters will not be expanded when they occur in single quoted strings.`

Comment: It worked when I changed it to double quotation .. thank you soo much ...

Comment: $sql = "SELECT id, AssignmentName, file, deadline,name,module FROM Assignment_scripts where module={$module}";

Answer (score 1):

PHP doesn't do variable substitution inside single quotes - you should change single quotes to double quotes and it will work.

In other words, if $x = 5, '$x' is $x but "$x" is 5.